# how to extract specific text from a group of columns in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have to extract specific column values against each row. Example table below:

For each item I would only like to extract if apple exists, however, apply can occur in any of the columns from Description 1 - Description 3. It does not follow any pattern except that the value is always called "Apple:"

Is there a quick/simple way to extract this info?

[image]

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following formula:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>E2</kbd>

```
=TOCOL(IFS(TEXTBEFORE(B2:D4,":")="apple",B2:D4),2)
```

---

Or,

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>E2</kbd>

```
=TOCOL(IFS(LEFT(B2:D4,5)="apple",B2:D4),3)
```

---

Or, if you are in `MS365` and have the `Beta Channel` enabled then could try this using <kbd>BYROW()</kbd> without <kbd>LAMBDA()</kbd> construct!

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>E2</kbd>

```
=BYROW(REPT(B2:D4,N(LEFT(B2:D4,5)="apple")),CONCAT)
```

---

Or,

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>E2</kbd>

```
=TOCOL(IF(1-ISERR(SEARCH("apple",B2:D4)),B2:D4,p),3)
```

---

Or,

[image]

---

```
=BYROW(IF(1-ISERR(SEARCH("apple",B2:D4)),B2:D4,""),CONCAT)
```

---

Or,

```
=BYROW(IF(LEFT(B2:D4,5)="apple",B2:D4,""),CONCAT)
```

---

Answer (score 0):

=BYROW(B2:D4,LAMBDA(x,XLOOKUP(TRUE,ISNUMBER(SEARCH("apple",x)),x)))

An alternative could be LAMBDA along with it's helper BYROW.
[image: how to extract specific text from a group of columns in excel]